# Whenever I deploy my Lambda functions and try to test it, it fails and generates the error below

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sam

This Lambda function inserts a JSON object from request body into Postgres table.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    
    initialId = data["initials_id"]
    ageId = data["age_id"]
    roleId = data["role_id"]
    gradeId = data["grade_id"]
    symptomaticId = data["symptomatic_id"]
    maskedId = data["masked_id"]
    testedId = data["tested_id"]
    testDateId = data["test_date_id"]
    studentTotalContacts =  data["student_total_contacts"]
    studentUnmaskedContacts =  data["student_unmasked_contacts"]
    studentsTested = data["students_tested"]
    studentsPositive = data["students_positive"]
    studentsPositiveAfterUmContact = data["students_positive_after_um_contact"]
    teacherContacts = data["teacher_contacts"]
    teacherUnmaskedContacts = data["teacher_unmasked_contacts"]
    teacherTested = data["teachers_tested"]
    teachersPositive = data["teachers_positive"]
    teachersPositveAfterUmContact = data["teachers_positive_after_um_contact"]

    
    query_sql=f"""
            INSERT INTO wustl.contact_tracker_submissions (initials_id, age_id, role_id, grade_id, symptomatic_id, masked_id,
                                                           tested_id, test_date_id, student_total_contacts, student_unmasked_contacts,
                                                           students_tested, students_positive, students_positive_after_um_contact,
                                                           teacher_contacts, teacher_unmasked_contacts, teachers_tested, teachers_positive,
                                                           teachers_positive_after_um_contact )

                  VALUES({initialId}, {ageId}, {roleId}, {gradeId}, {symptomaticId}, {maskedId}, {testedId}, {testDateId}, {studentTotalContacts},
                         {studentUnmaskedContacts}, {studentsTested}, {studentsPositive}, {studentsPositiveAfterUmContact}, {teacherContacts},
                         {teacherUnmaskedContacts}, {teacherTested}, {teachersPositive}, {teachersPositveAfterUmContact});
        """


    # execute the sql query and get the response
    try:
        response = execute_statement(query_sql)
        results = 'Successfully submitted'
        status_code = 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        results = 'Failed'
        status_code = 500

    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body':  json.dumps({"message" : results})
    }
```

line 30 --> initialId = data["initials_id"]

Here is the event payload:

```
{"initials_id":"BS","age_id":23,"role_id":"Student","grade_id":10,"symptomatic_id":true,"masked_id":true,"tested_id":true,"test_date_id":"2022-02-10T17:25:00.000Z","student_total_contacts":1,"student_unmasked_contacts":2,"students_tested":3,"students_positive":4,"students_postive_after_um_contact":5,"teacher_contacts":6,"teacher_unmasked_contacts":7,"teachers_tested":8,"teachers_positive":9,"teachers_positive_after_um_contact":10}
```

Here is the error log it generates

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'initials_id'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/contactTracker.py\", line 30, in lambda_handler\n    initialId = event[\"initials_id\"]\n"]}
Wed Mar 02 19:44:04 UTC 2022 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'initials_id'. Lambda request id: cd2146ab-b914-4048-bd4b-b863946d9d20
Wed Mar 02 19:44:04 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the data does not contain a key named `initials_id`.

Comment: Is `line 30`  your SQL query?

Comment: line 30  --> initialId = data["initials_id"]

Comment: Your `event` does not seem to contain a `body` element.  Have you printed `event` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: @TimRoberts It must contain a body element, otherwise `json.loads(event["body"])` would have thrown a key error.

Comment: Can you show the outcome of `print(event)`?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think you need to use `data = json.loads(event["body"])` -- just use `initialId = event["initials_id"]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you print the value of `data` and confirm `initials_id` exist in the data